Different cookie settings for different web views
I am working on an application which shows a list of web views in a recyclerview. There can be 2 kinds of web views in this list

Authentication web views: Which load all the urls including those which require authentication (Authentication is managed via CookieManager).
Non-authentication web views: Which load all the urls except those which require authentication. For authentication urls, these web views should show login page to user and once logged in should move to the url.

Now the issue I am running into is that CookieManager is a singleton. If I change cookie settings for web view #2, it affects the authenticated urls in web view #1 and vice versa [since it's a recycler view so the state of CookieManager is a bit unpredictable when web views in different view-holders load the url].
A hack is to create different instances of CookieManager but it is deprecated and might become a system API in future.
This is how the cookies are set in web view #1.
    binding.webView.enableThirdPartyCookie(true)
    binding.webView.enableCookie(true)
    binding.webView.setCookies("https://" + Uri.parse(webViewUrl).host, getCookies())

This is how they are cleared in web view #2 in onPageStarted
    if (url.startsWith("https://authdomain")) {
         CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(false);
    }

Anyone who has faced a similar problem and found any solution to this?
I have tried changing cookie settings in either of the web views, but still facing issues.
I checked with iOS developers and they have a concept of persistent/non-persistent cookies which allows them custom settings for different web views. I didn't find any similar APIs on Android.
Also, explored other SO threads or links but didn't find a solution to this problem.

Manually inject cookies into each WebView based on whether it's an authenticated or non-authenticated WebView. Override WebViewClient methods to handle authentication logic directly.

@BobSmith I tried your suggestion and just to test, added a check in non-authenticated web view's onPageStarted method that if it's an authenticated url, clear the cookies, or don't accept cookies. But due to the nature of recycler view, this ends up affecting the other webview (authenticated one) in the list.
I think this will work in case the web views are not part of same page/list.

Can you post the necessary code block to review your use case and then help.

Added relevant code, let me know if any other info is required.

Please post the complete recycler view adapter Its very difficult to say anything from that much of code part. Your issue seems to more with the recycler view rather than webView cookies settings.

@BobSmith Can you please suggest what areas are you specifically looking to check in recycler view code. Asking this since the code is quite complex with multiple widgets inside recycler view, and nested recycler views as well. It will be a bit difficult to post the entire code. If you can suggest some areas where I can check, I will look into the code. Thanks for your help.

Post functions like onCreateViewHolder  , onBindViewHolder , getItemId , getItemViewType  and classes like ViewHolder. May help us to look more deep into code.
